# Upgrading to MacOS 10.15, now it says that system is read-only

Tags: macos, catalina

The latest OS by Apple moved all of my folders into the `Security` folder. Now all my folders which were on root are not able to move on root anymore and it gives the message: `mkdir: myDir: Read-only file system`.

Before my folders were on `/`. For example `/Developerment`. It is not there anymore. I did find my folders under `Security` folders but can't copy on root now.

What should I do?

Comment: Can you please clarify *"moved all of my folders"*? When you say 'all', which folders do you mean? Or do you literally mean *all* folders? Otherwise, macOS Catalina by design creates a read-only partition for the system to further protect/isolate it from user data.

Comment: @Monomeeth I mean the Custom folders I had created like `Videos`, `Development` etc. They were now `/`. Now I can't keep there as it is `readonly`. Where can I keep those folders now?

Comment: Ok, it'd be good if you could add those examples to your question and also include where it was these folders were located previously. By the way, do you have a backup of your data (Time Machine or otherwise)?

Comment: @Monomeeth My data is all intact.

Comment: Shouldn't have ever been off the root anyway. Put them in your user folder.

Comment: @MarcWilson: I'd generally agree, except a lot of companies put some special folders in the root folders for management purposes, so I'd say it may not be up to the OP's choice.

Comment: @haylem But in this case, obviously it is not that issue.

Comment: @MarcWilson: Interesting show of (over-)confidence here... I said that because I have exactly that issue, just with a different folder name. It is enforced by a customer's IT department, because they allow power users (e.g. developers) to have *one* sub-tree of the filesystem where the IT-enforced anti-virus won't bug them and kill their machine's performance. E.g., a place where you want disk intensive stuff to reside, like your IDE's workspaces and caches, for instance, so on-access virus scanning won't make your build slow down to an excruciating halt...

Comment: @MarcWilson: So... again, while I *agree* with you that this is a *bad* habit and approach, I wouldn't really blatantly say that this cause isn't it. At least I can't say that from the details the OP gives. And it's not an outlandish scenario. It's fine totally fine to *ask* the OP to clarify and see if changing that habit/approach wouldn't be better, or possible, though. And to try to understand why they did that (there's generally a reason: anti-virus bypass, issues with specific or long paths, etc...).